# Android ListView is reloading all of the items (rather than just appending the new item) after I return back from a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Android ListView is reloading all of the items (rather than just appending the new item) after I return back from a fragment where i inserted a new item onto the listview (in another fragment, ListFragment)

I have the following code to launch a fragment through Navigation Drawer:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    SherlockFragment frag = null;
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        frag = ListFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
        break;
    case 1:
        frag = InsertNewsFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
        break;
    default:
        frag = UnderConstructionFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();
    listview.setItemChecked(position, true);

    drawlayout.closeDrawer(listview);
```

The issue is that when I initially load the activity ListFragment is launched, but when user opens the navigation drawer and selects the add News, I replace the current fragment with the InsertNewsFragment, the insertNewsFragment adds data to the adapter that is displayed in the ListFragment. After adding the news element, the user selects the list fragment option in the navigation drawer, but I would expect the same listview to be there and just append the new data to the listview. But what happens is that the whole listview is loaded from scratch again. Can show me the way to how item can be appended to the list view when I return from another fragment, and not reload the whole listview. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please add you adapter implementation code in the activity

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this as you are replacing the listfragment. Initially you will have to check if the  listview is opened if it comes out to be true then close all the other fragments that are opened and bring it (The listview fragment) to the top then dont set the adapter again and again just use the notifydatasetchanged method

Comment: after the listview is at the top (opened), what if the user wants to switch to a different fragment (through the navigation drawer), should I be pushing the listview fragment on a stack and pop it back off?

Comment: yes add it to the backstack with a tag and dont use replace,use add for it.Once it is added set a flag to be true. then if next time the user clicks on the the listfragment search for that tag in the backstack and pop all the fragments added above it